# Powers of two my children be

Tags: riddle, mathematics, rhyme

> *Powers of two my children be,*
>   *Arriving in birth years separately.*
>
> *Their sum is now the reverse of me*
>   *And the years between me and a power of three.*
>
> *My digit difference is the number you see*
>   *And my digits are powers of binary.*
>
> *And now the question I ask of thee:*
>   *Their number and age, and the age that I be.*

A little riddle I came up with for my sons birthday.

Comment: i hope your son is a genius

Comment: @pietz: Well, I didn't make it *for* him. I just came up with it on his birthday, since he was the last one to turn a power of two.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
Powers of two my children be,
Arriving in birth years separately.
```

> Unspecified number of children but no twins and their age is 2^n.

```
Their sum is now the reverse of me
```

> Their sum can be any number since any number can be expressed as a sum of powers of two. Your age can be written `10d + u` and the sum of their age `10u + d`.

```
And the years between me and a power of three.
```

> `10d + u - 3^x = 10u + d` or `3^x - (10d + u) = 10u + d`
>  Therefore `3^x = 9(u - d)` or `3^x = 11(u + d)`
>  The latter has no solution but the former has many solutions: (u - d) just needs to be a power of three

```
My digit difference is the number you see
```

> The difference is the number of children: you have either three or nine children.

```
And my digits are powers of binary.
```

> There are four possible digits: 1, 2, 4 and 8
>  If their difference is a power of three (= 3), they can only be 1 and 4.

```
And now the question I ask of thee:
Their number and age, and the age that I be.
```

> You are 41 and the sum of their age is 14 (1110 in binary). Therefore you have three children and they are 8, 4 and 2 years old.

Comment: You got it! And very nice proof by the way. I wasn't even expecting a formula since I actually worked out the clues to give by just brute-force checking all combinations.

Comment: Thank you @gnovice That was a nice, fun-to-solve puzzle.

Comment: @xhienne Where do you get the 10 in 10d+u from?

Comment: @Orphevs: If my age is made of two individual digits `d` and `u`, then my age will be `10*d+u` (i.e. `d` is in the tens place, `u` is in the ones place).

Comment: @gnovice Thank you, I forgot about base 10 for a second.

Answer (score 3):

> I know this answer is pretty unlikely, but it DOES fit the hints. You are 21, kids are 8 and 4.

Powers of two my children be,

> 8 and 4 are 2^3 and 2^2

Arriving in birth years separately.

> Not the same age!

Their sum is now the reverse of me

> 8 + 4 = 12 which is the reverse of 21

And the years between me and a power of three.

> 21 - 9 = 12. 9 is a power of 3, 3^2

My digit difference is the number you see

> I don't know what this means

And my digits are powers of binary.

> 2 = 2^1. 1 = 2^0

And now the question I ask of thee:

Their number and age, and the age that I be.

> You are 21, kids are 8 and 4.

Comment: So, I had a kid at 13, eh? ;) We're getting closer! It satisfies all the criteria except the fifth line.

Comment: It seemed unlikely but you never know!

Answer (score 1):

> Your children are 32 and 4. You are 63.

Powers of two my children be,

Arriving in birth years separately.

> 4 and 32 are powers of 2. They'd obviously be born in separate years.

Their sum is now the reverse of me

> 32+4=36. 63 Is the reverse.

And the years between me and a power of three.

> 63-36=27, a power of 3. (36 being their sum and 63 being your age.)

And my digits are powers of binary.

> Least sure about this one - not sure what a "power of binary" really means. But at a guess, 63 is 0b111111 - all the digits are 1.

Comment: How about the fifth line? And "powers of binary" was just another way of saying "powers of two" in a way that rhymed. ;) Also, you should try to use [spoiler text](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers).

Comment: @gnovice Ah, I missed that line! And I figured it may not be right considering the last line anyway, but thought I'd give it a go.